# What is a valid WMTS Capabilites TileMatrixLimits element if the TileMatrixSet MatrixWidth or MatrixHeight is 1

Tags: wmts, ogc, getcapabilities

In a OGC WMTS 1.0.0 capabilities document, part of the **TileMatrixSetLink** is the  **TileMatrixSetLimits** element.  It contains a list of **TileMatrixLimits** elements, which in turn specify the dataset extent in terms of the min/max column/row.  There must be one **TileMatrixLimits** for each **TileMatrix** in the **TileMatrixSet**.

The **TileMatrixLimits** element **MaxTileRow** is listed as:

```
Maximim tile row index valid for this layer. From minTileRow to matrixWidth-1 of the tileMatrix section of this tileMatrixSet
```

The Xml schema document lists the **MaxTileRow** type as **positiveIntegers**, which exclude zero.

Ignoring the fact that the description references the matrix width instead of height, how is a **TileMatrix** with a **MatrixHeight** equal to one handled?  From what I can tell, this can't be represented by a **TileMatrixLimit**, which means that the whole **TileMatrixSetLimits** element has to be removed.

Based on the description of **MaxTileRow**, shouldn't the Xml type be **nonNegativeInteger**?

Looking at the WMTS 1.0.1 schema, **MinTileRow** and **MaxTileRow** are both type **PositiveInteger**.

http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/

Comment: that's why the change was made in 1.0.1 I think

Comment: Schema wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd, version 1.0.1 still has all mins and maxs as `<element name="MinTileCol" type="positiveInteger">`.  In the standard the  UTM model is using "integer" but table 12 is using "positive integer" but the note says `From 0 to maxTileRow` so it means non-negative integer. Just accept that standards do have errors and that 0 is OK as a value. I hope that your XML validator accepts it as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I maintain the server and another organization's client is balking...